ActionText is blocked , can anyone explain why this is happening?
Recently, I migrated the whole codebase from Rails 5.2 to 7, but the folder structure is still the same as the earlier version.
I also implemented ActionText, but the text field is blocked when I try to enter it; it is fully blocked on the rendered page.
I tried some possible way from installing to debugging but nothing works . LIKE:-
Since my code was in Rails 5, the folder structure remained the same but i have migrated whole code to rails 7 . However, when I migrated, i also installed Turbo, it created another folder, javascript, in the app directory.
Then I installed ActionText. The steps I followed are:

rails action_text:install

rails db:migrate

rails assets:precompile

Imported actiontext and trix in application.js

Added has_rich_text and rich_text_area

Also check server console , its coming on that desciption



<trix-editor id="portal_product_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description" input="portal_product_description_trix_input_portal_product_10420" data-direct-upload-url="http://localhost:3030/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" data-blob-url-template="http://localhost:3030/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/:filename"></trix-editor>



Please help me guys i am in need of this ?

product.html.erb
 <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :description %>
      <%= form.rich_text_area :description, id: :portal_product_description,class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Enter description"%>
    </div>



product.rb
  has_rich_text :description



application.js in app/javascript folder
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
// application.js
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"

Turbo.start()



What do you mean by “blocked”?
